# Facebook How to get my location and all my friends location

Tags: facebook, permissions

Using this permission,i can get my location user_hometown.

How do i get my friend location?

Is that possible?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried permissions `friends_location` and `friends_hometown` ?
I don't think it'll work with `user_hometown` or `user_location` only, you'll need the friend permissions.
Edit:
Just checked with [graph api explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer). In addition to `friends_location` and `friends_hometown` permissions you'll also need the `friends_about_me` permission.