# Get Friends Location using Facebook Graph API & HybridAuth

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, hybridauthprovider

**Problem**

I am trying to get `friends_location` from the Facebok Graph API. I am accessing the API using the [HybridAuth](http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/) framework. **How do I return a friend's location/hometown etc?**

**My App Permissions**

I have set the following permissions for my app:

`friends_about_me,friends_location,friends_hometown,user_location,email,user_birthday,offline_access,user_hometown`

This is the request for permission screen the user sees on Facebook:
[image: Facebook Permissions Screen]

**What I Have Tried**

I have tried the following methods to get the friend's details:

HybridAuth: `$hybrid->getUserContacts();`

and

Native API: `$hybrid->api()->api('/me/friends');`

Both return the following format without the friend's location:

`{"identifier": "12345678","displayName": "Joe Smith",},`

I have also seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8307085/facebook-how-to-get-my-location-and-all-my-friends-location) question but I have already included the `friends_about_me` permission in my request.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the Graph API explorer:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Click on the "Get access token" button and select (under the Friends Data Permissions tab):

- friends_hometown
- friends_location

Once you have given the permissions for the access token click the friends link under connections in the right hand column. Your GET request should now look something like this:

https://graph.facebook.com/123456789/friends

You should now have a list of your friends with their name and id. If you click on the id you will see the results for that friend which include the hometown and location.

Hope that helps.